# R - How to enter value to input field on webpage and get resulting page for scraping?

Tags: r, api, web-scraping

I'm working with this [genealogical website](https://www.ancestry.com/learn/facts/) that has a single input field. I would like to programmatically enter a surname and have the resulting page returned as an object that I can then scrape. I have some experience with the scraping part but not working with input fields. Where would I look to find more about this corner of webscraping in R?

Comment: the website on passing surname have url like `https://www.ancestry.com/name-origin?surname=`, so you just have to `rvest::read_html(paste0(url, "john"))` (eg.john) for getting that webpage

Comment: @parth There's Occam's razor.

Comment: You've read http://www.ancestry.com/cs/legal/termsandconditions (#2) right? Anyone who decides to help should read that, too. They also [don't publish an API](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/10552/does-ancestry-com-have-a-developer-api). Think very carefully before proceeding or helping.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Those are important considerations, thanks for pointing them out.